# How to replacing multiple shell pipeline

Tags: python

In the Python 2.7 documentation of subprocess module, it provides a simple solution to replace the shell pipeline:

```
p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

I want to have a **wrapper function** that can support multiple `|` in command.

Yes, the easiest solution is to set `Shell=True` which makes the program vulnerable to shell injection.

I'm wondering if there is a neat way to support both multiple `|` and keep `Shell=False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there is a neat way to support both multiple `|` and keep `shell=False`

Yes, the two-command example from the documentation works for any number of commands in the pipeline:

```
p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
p3 = Popen(["grep", "-v", "audio"], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p2.stdout.close()
output = p3.communicate()[0]
```

For clarity and convenience, this can be extracted to a utility function:

```
import subprocess

def pipe(*arglists):
    prev_proc = subprocess.Popen(arglists[0], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for args in arglists[1:]:
       proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=prev_proc.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
       prev_proc.stdout.close()
       prev_proc = proc
    return prev_proc

>>> p = pipe(["dmesg"], ["grep", "hda"], ["grep", "-v", "audio"])
>>> p.communicate()
('[    2.654606] snd_hda_intel 0000:0f:00.1: Disabling MSI\n', None)
```